# closed loop optimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the following loop:

```
for I=1:N
  x = f(x);
end
```

with f being a custom function, i.e. an anonymous function.
Is there a command like arrayfun that allows this?

edit: May be vectorization is the wrong word here, and rather optimization should be used.

Comment: what is `x` and how `I` is related to it???

Comment: x is a vector and not related to I.

Comment: I suppose you want to store each value of f(x) in x. For that, you should `x(I) = f(x)`.

Comment: Can you post code for f, it might be possible to program it in such a way that you can just go `x = f(x)`...

Comment: Since f should be adaptable this would not help me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't check the code, but maybe:

`x = arrayfun(@(y) f(x), 1:N);`

With `arrayfun` you can take each element of the vector you passed as parameter. In the example above, `y` refers to each element of the vector `1:N`, which also represents the index of the `for` loop you posted as example. In your `for` loop you do not use the index so you can do the same in the `arrayfun` and iterate over a vector doing what you want inside: `f(x)`. Finally you can assign the output to `x`. Possibly, with the `arrayfun` way you retrieve an output `x` of length `N` with the result of each `f(x)` in the iterations. With the `for` loop you overwrite in each iteration the value of `x`.

Hope you help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the code does not seem to work for me. And for large N and non-scalar x this might not be very memory efficient.